# Qt How to Prevent dropping item FROM application TO Windows File Explorer

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a clean and cross-platform way to Prevent dropping an item FROM a Qt application TO Windows File Explorer (or other OS equiv.)

The following diagram shows the desired behavior:
[image]

I haven't had luck finding examples online or hacking a work-around together, but it seems like it would be a common-enough use-case that there would be a well designed and implemented solution floating around.

What I've tried and do not have working:

- **Detecting the Drag and Killing It:**

  1. detecting the QDragEnterEvent, QDragMoveEvent, QDragLeaveEvent
  2. comparing the answerRect() or pos() of the event to the Geometry of
     the Window or Widget to detect if the drag has left the application

  This is pretty hacky (and not working at them moment) and I'm hoping you can point me towards a more elegant solution.

(UPDATE - tried changing mimeType, but Windows File Explorer still accepts the drop)

- **Changing the MIME Type to a custom type:**

  1. Pre: the "Widget w/ Drag & Drop" from the diagram above is a `QTreeView` with a `QFileSystemModel` model
  2. Sub-classing the `QFileSystemModel` and overriding the `mimeTypes()` function like the code below
  3. From the `qDebug()` output, it looks like the mimeType is correctly being set, but Windows File Explorer still accepts the drop :/

> ```
> QStringList MyFileSystemModel::mimeTypes() const  
> {  
>     QStringList customMimeTypes;  
>     customMimeTypes << QString("UnicornsAndRainbows/uri-list");  
>     qDebug() << "customMimeTypes: " << customMimeTypes;
>     return customMimeTypes;  
> }
> ```

Please let me know when you have a chance.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Just fill mime type to any custom string.

Comment: after checking the `mimeType` on the `dropEvent`, I see that my above implementation was __not__ setting the `mimeType` correctly.  I currently have some code working for my use case from the [4.8 Drag and Drop Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html) and will post my code once I clean it up.  Thanks Dmitry! :)

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry Sazonov gave the correct answer.  I will explain how I implemented it below. Dmitry, if you want cred, post it as an answer and not a comment so I can accept it as the answer.

What I did wrong on my question update based on Dmitry's suggestion was to override the `QFileSystemModel::mimeTypes()` when, in fact, I had to modify the `QTreeView::mouseMoveEvent()` and `QTreeView::dropEvent()`.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
void MyTreeView::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event )
{
    if( !(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) )
    {
        return; // we only care about left mouse drags at the moment
    }

    if( (event->pos() - dragStartPosition).manhattanLength() < QApplication::startDragDistance() )
    {
        return; // a buffer when calculating waht qualifies as a "drag event"
    }

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag( this );
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData();
    QByteArray data;
    const QStringList selectedPaths = this->getSelectedPaths(); // custom helper method

    foreach( QString path, selectedPaths )
    {
        data.append( path ).append( ";" ); // using ';' as path deliminator
    }
    data.chop( 1 );

    //--- this sets the custom MIME Type filter 
    mimeData->setData( CUSTOM_MIMETYPE_STRING, data );

    drag->setMimeData( mimeData );

    Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec( Qt::CopyAction );
}


//---------------------------------------------------------
void MyTreeView::dropEvent( QDropEvent *event )
{
    // ...

    QList<QByteArray> paths;

    //--- this filters based on our custom MIME Type
    paths = event->mimeData()->data( CUSTOM_MIMETYPE_STRING ).split(';');

    foreach( QByteArray path, paths )
    {
        // do something with the file paths
    }
}
```

Comment: also note that the silly "Widget Container Moat" should not be used as the proper solution is to use custom MIME Types.

Comment: I tried this, but now i cannot drop the data in my own application, do i have to register this custom mimetype anywhere?